# CSS Display:Inline-Block Pairs

Tags: html, css

I need a CSS **only** solution to make pairs of `<a>` tags inline, but not all in a row. For example, in this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vLakfsLv/, I want two rows of two black squares.

```html
<div>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
</div>
```

```css
a{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Obviously you can do this by wrapping the `<a>` tags with `<div>`s but I need a CSS hack. I cannot edit the HTML.

EDIT:

Please don't accomplish this with `width` because the `width` is constantly changing.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/vLakfsLv/2/

Comment: Without using width too. Width is changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float everything to the left, make your third `<a>` tag (using `a:nth-child(3)`) clear the floats to the left. [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Morklympious/vLakfsLv/6/)

Comment: add one more `<a></a>` and this won't work. `a:nth-child(2n+1)` for pairs.

Answer (score 3):

Why not display:block and float:left to the `<a>` and a clear:left to the correct nth-child ?

( you didn't say you needed IE* support )

Answer (score 1):

you could give them margins, specifically left or rights, and/or give the surrounding div (of the four blocks) a set width. they will adjust to that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
div {
    width: 240px; /* 100 + 20 + 100 + 20 */
    font-size: 0; /* To avoid additional space */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vLakfsLv/3/)

You don't need `font-size: 0` if you get rid of spaces in between elements:

```
<div><!--
    --><a></a><!--
    --><a></a><!--
    --><a></a><!--
    --><a></a><!--
--></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a{
    float: left;
}
a:nth-child(odd){
    clear: both;
}
div {
    overflow: hidden; /* Clear float */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vLakfsLv/4/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use float like this:

```
a{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color:black;
}
a:nth-child(3n){
    clear:both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vLakfsLv/8/